# NHibernate HasManyToMany automapping not populating list on load

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I've got a many-to-many relationship set up via AutoMapping.  Now, the save and updates work fine as expected, however the DiscountGroups are not being loaded in DiscountDay when I get the entities afterwards.  I cannot for the life of me work out why the _discountGroups list is always empty, even though it's all correct in the database.

I've seen suggestions about using ISet rather than IList however it doesn't seem to make any difference in my case, neiter does using
    .Not.LazyLoad()
in the mapping.  Removing AsBag() and AsSet() also makes no difference.

**The Entities**

```
public class DiscountDay
{
    public virtual DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public virtual Discount Discount { get; set; }

    private readonly IList<DiscountGroup> _discountGroups = new List<DiscountGroup>();

    public virtual IEnumerable<DiscountGroup> DiscountGroups
    {
        get { return _discountGroups; }
        set { }
    }
}

public class DiscountGroup
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    private readonly IList<DiscountDay> _discountDay = new List<DiscountDay>();

    public virtual IEnumerable<DiscountDay> DiscountDay 
    {
        get { return _discountDay; }
    }
}
```

**The Mappings**

```
public class DiscountDayOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<DiscountDay>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<DiscountDay> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasManyToMany( x => x.DiscountGroups )
            .AsSet()
            .Cascade
            .SaveUpdate();
        mapping.Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}

public class DiscountGroupOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<DiscountGroup>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<DiscountGroup> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasManyToMany( x => x.DiscountDay )
            .AsBag()
            .Inverse();
        mapping.Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm a complete and utter numpty.  The empty set on DiscountGroups on the DiscountDay entity was causing the issue.  For some reason I'd glossed over it and just didn't think that an empty set would do anything.

Updated code:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<DiscountGroup> DiscountGroups
{
    get { return _discountGroups; }
}
```